# Using get_posts() to return media files of a specific category only returns some of the posts

Tags: wordpress

I have uploaded 11 jpg files to the media library using the normal admin dashboard media library tools. These will be used for background images. In the media file editor I applied a new category called "pw-background". So now, 11 media files have `pw-background` as their category. In the function.php of my child theme, I added the following code to return all posts with the new category. Here is the code:

```
function adjust_background_image(){
        $args = array(
                        'category_name' => 'pw-background',
                        'post_type' => 'attachment'
                    );
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($attachments); // An array with only 5 elements is returned. 
        echo "</pre>";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'adjust_background_image');
```

When I run the page, what happens is that only the last five media files I uploaded and tagged with the `pw-background` are returned. So, `count($attachments)` = 5 when it should equal 11. The code returns media files with the correct category, but only the last five out of a total of 11 images with the same category.

Why is the function returning only some of the posts, and how do I get all of the posts of a given category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TARKUS you should add 'numberposts' parameter to the $args array to control the number of posts retrieved from get_posts() wordpress function, as specified in the codex:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Hope this helps

Comment: I guess the "why" is spelled out here: $args
        'numberposts'
        (int) Total number of posts to retrieve. Is an alias of $posts_per_page in WP_Query. Accepts -1 for all. Default 5. Your answer worked.